# Cloning drive and the length of time it should take

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, clone

I am using EaseUS Todo Backup Free to clone a 1.81 TB external hard drive with 1.5 TB of data onto a 4TB external hard drive. It has been 47 hours and the estimated remaining time continues to increase and only the destination drive has any activity (100% active time, ~1 MB/Second). I was wondering if this was normal and if is not normal, what I should do.

(Windows 10 laptop.)

Comment: It is not normal.  It sounds like the source drive has significant number of bad sectors on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used EaseUS but the transfer speed seems possibly too low. Assuming it was operating correctly, this would take something like a couple weeks or more to finish. While it could simply be a "difficult" file or folder (or set of them), I would probably consider trying again if it seemed to be continuing indefinitely.

That said, even at a (relatively quick) one gigabyte every few minutes (~5 - 20 MB/second), you are still likely looking at anywhere from 24 to 72 hours for 1.5 TB of data. Also note that external hard drives can be slowed by their connections and hardware, so backups to an external drive may take longer than backups to an internal drive. Likewise, any additional mirroring to a cloud/network storage environment could have a significant impact on speed.